# Convert string Fri, 04 Aug 2017 13:07:44 into 04-08-2017 in unix

Tags: unix

I would like to convert the date `" Fri, 04 Aug 2017 13:07:44 GMT "` into `04-08-2017` .
And code should recursively convert all string format into specified format.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the -d option with date command.

Execute this in your command line to get the desired output.

```
date -d 'Fri, 04 Aug 2017 13:07:44 GMT' +'%d-%m-%Y'
```

Edit :

If you want to populate it in a script you may use something like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 input_date="Fri, 04 Aug 2017 13:07:44 GMT"
 output_date=$(date -d "$input_date" +'%d-%m-%Y')
 echo $output_date
```